# How to override flutter's webview default alert?

Tags: flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I'm using pub `webview_flutter: ^3.0.1` to display webview
However, when the target website displays a pop-up alert it appears as attached:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y16NJ.png)

How to override this to display a popup of my own?
I already tried

```
javascriptChannels: Set.from([
              JavascriptChannel(
                name: 'Alert',
                onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
                  // alert message = Test alert Message
                  print(message.message);
                  // TODO popup
                },
              )
            ]),
```

But I'm not receiving any response in that callback method `onMessageReceived`

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Same case happened to me Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

you can use onJsAlert for web view and don't forget to make handledByClient to be true

```
onJsAlert: (controller, jsAlertRequest)async{
print(jsAlertRequest.message);
// DO ur Logic herel
return JsAlertResponse(handledBvClient:true):
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when answering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Try to [edit] your answer and copy-paste it into the answer itself in between \`\`\` the_code \`\`\`.